# Accessing a property from a service in a template

Tags: ember.js, service, properties

I have a user service that manages reading data from localstorage, it has a property that reads from the local storage a certain object property, the service is setup like so

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LocalUser from 'bidr/models/user-local';

const {
  computed: {
    alias
  }
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  localUser: LocalUser.create(),
  user_id: alias('localUser.user.id'),
  active_auction: alias('localUser.user.active_auction')
});
```

In my route.js file for my `item` route I inject the service like so

```
user: Ember.inject.service('user'),
```

And in the template I'm attempting to access it like so

```
{{user.active_auction}}
```

I was under the impression I could do that but is that not the case? Do I need to set a property on the `item` route that is equal to the service property to make this work?

Comment: the route isn't the scope in the template.  It's the controller associated with that route (even though controllers are on their way out, and route-able components are on their way in). Meaning you'd need to inject the service on the controller

Comment: Sidenote, you should probably initialize `localUser` in the `init` method instead.

Comment: +1 to @Kingpin2k's answer ... there is no other way at the moment. But if you don't want to create a controller file for it, I did it by declaring it within the route. So in your beforeModel, you can do a this.controllerFor('routeName').set('user', this.get('user'));

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a controller for this template's scope, you can expose the service to the template by setting a property in the auto-generated controller via the route's [`setupController`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController) hook, like so:

```
// application/some-route.js

export default Route.extend({
    user: service(),

    setupController(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        set(controller, 'user', get(this, user))
    }
});
```